# Track changes on 2+ columns using OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a `dbo.ChangeLog` table that we insert changes to certain columns.
The normal way I do this is something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET FirstName = NewFirstName
OUTPUT
Deleted.Id
'FirstName' as Type
Deleted.FirstName as OldValue
Inserted.FirstName as NewValue
INTO dbo.ChangeLog
FROM dbo.Table as t
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 as t2 on t.Id = t2.Id
```

When I need to update `FirstName` AND `LastName`, for example, I usually do 2 update statements, but I am wondering if it's possible to update multiple columns in the same update statement, while also inserting the changes into the `dbo.ChangeLog` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the definition of dbo.ChangeLog it becomes trivial, but I'm assuming that's not really what you want.

I'd handle this with a table variable and "unpivot" the data using `CROSS APPLY` (but would probably work fine using `UNPIVOT` too...):

```
SELECT 1 as id, 'Dan                        ' as FirstName, 'Field                               ' as LastName INTO #tbl

DECLARE @changes TABLE (id int, old1 varchar(250), new1 varchar(250), old2 varchar(250), new2 varchar(250))

UPDATE  #tbl
SET FirstName = 'asdf', LastName = NEWID()
OUTPUT deleted.id
        ,deleted.FirstName, inserted.FirstName
        ,deleted.LastName, inserted.LastName 
    INTO @changes(id, old1, new1, old2, new2)

-- change this to an INSERT dbo.ChangeLog
SELECT unp.*
FROM @changes
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (id, old1, new1)
                    ,(id, old2, new2)) unp(id, oldval, newval)


DROP TABLE #tbl
```

Just change that last SELECT into an INSERT.  And note that this requires an intermediate table variable or temp table, because you can't use `CROSS APPLY` or `UNPIVOT` in an `OUTPUT` clause.